# How to print intervals of data in a for loop (if else statement)? Python Question

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

**Hi everyone! I read in a CDF file with the date, time, latitude, and longitude of a satellite in orbit. I am trying to write up a txt file that saves the data every time the satellite hovers over an Arctic station (I have it's LAT and LON with a small error value).**

**I managed to save a txt file with the appropriate conditions, but it is way too much data to look through and outputs this:**

2013-01-09 02:05:00 -57.097008  40.165134

2013-01-09 02:06:00 -57.29849   40.504826

2013-01-09 02:07:00 -57.49554   40.834732

2013-01-09 02:08:00 -57.68884   41.154243

2013-01-09 02:09:00 -57.881386  41.45857

etc.

**Several years of data equals way too much to handle... Essentially, I want to find a way for the code to show intervals of time. So instead of minute by minute, it would be more like:**

2013-09-01 02:00:00 ~ 2013-09-01 02:14:00

2013-10-05 04:23:00 ~ 2013-10-05 04:32:00

**The code I used was:**

```
From spacepy import cdf
import datetime
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

cdf = pycdf.CDF('/directory/file.cdf')
print(cdf)


TIME = cdf['EPOCH']
LAT = cdf['SouthBtrace_GM_LAT']
LON = cdf['SouthBTrace_GM_LON']    

#Loop Count
count = 0
    
with open("example.txt", "a") as testing:
    for i, j in zip(LAT, LON):
        if(-65.26 <= i <= -59.26 and 32.31 <= j <= 52.31):            
            count +=1
            n = count
            testing.write(str(TIME[n-1])+'\t'+str(i)+'\t'+str(j)+ '\n')
               
           
        else:
            count +=1
```

**Apologies if my question is confusing. I am new to programming and never used stackoverflow either.**

Edit:

```
>> type(TIME[0])
   datetime.datetime
```

Comment: How does the TIME value appear in the cdf file?

Comment: So it has three items: Epoch (Includes both date and time in one), Lat, and Lon. I don't know how to separate the date from the time. When I print(cdf) it outputs -> Epoch: CDF_EPOCH [525600], SouthBtrace_GM_LAT: CDF_FLOAT [525600], and SouthBtrace_GM_LON: CDF_FLOAT [525600]

Comment: You should take a closer look at [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects, especially the `timedelta` might be useful for you. Additionally, please specify a bit more how you want to group the outputs. Should it be grouped by a fixed time interval or only when the time difference to the previous time is smaller than a given value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my thought would be that you add in a time parameter and an additional 'if' condition that's met only when the time difference is great enough (10 minutes, or 15 minutes, or whatever you want). So, like:

```
import datetime
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 600) ## the time gap that you want to use
time_one = datetime.datetime(2020,9,16,5,26,0) ## some arbitrary starting value
with open("example.txt", "a") as testing:
    for i, j in zip(LAT, LON):
        if(-65.26 <= i <= -59.26 and 32.31 <= j <= 52.31):
            if TIME > time_one + delta: 
                count +=1
                n = count
                testing.write(str(TIME[n-1])+'\t'+str(i)+'\t'+str(j)+ '\n')
                time_one = TIME  ## resets the time_one value to the new time
        else:
            count +=1
```

That way, no new data will get written to the txt file unless the time value is at least 600 seconds (assuming the EPOCH value is in seconds ... if not, obviously use the appropriate units) later than the previous written entry.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding. I've been trying to figure it out. Problem is TIME format is: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second. It is not behaving as an array. I am trying to extract the Hour, Minute, and Second separately, but for the life of me it is not working. When I list(TIME) is gives me datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,16,35) etc.

Comment: OK. Then, as @Jakob Borchardt commented, you'll probably need to use datetime.timedelta. I've edited my answer above in a way that I think would work.

Comment: Last problem, thank you so much for helping me out... I ran the code and it stated: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Var' and 'datetime.datetime'. I have no clue as to what Var is

Comment: Most likely you copied the above code and tried to run it. However, `TIME` in your case is not a datetime object. You can achive that by extending the `for`-loop to `for i, j, t in zip(LAT, LON, TIME): ... if t > time_one + delta`. Could you add in your post above the result of `type(TIME[0])`?

Comment: I think I may found the answer to my problem, although I still have to figure out how to handle it. 'Var' is from spacepy.pycdf.Var.

Comment: I just posted it, it came out as: datetime.datetime

Comment: This works! I changed the method a bit for a different code, but this one works fine. Thank you very much!